# Merge HTTP Responses in Microsoft Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, http, httpresponse, azure-logic-apps

when my logic app got triggerd, i would like to merge two parallel executed HTTP Responses and send this back. Is it enough to tell the final response that it contains both bodys from the previous calls, as shown in the image? Can this cause problems?

Thank you in advance.

[HTTP Get Calls and Responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3TwT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks ok, the response will contain both of the bodys from the previous two http requests. I test it further, please refer to my testing logic app:

**1.** I created a logic app similar to yours, it works fine.

**2.** Then I modified the logic app with adding a "Delay" action before the second http request and set it delay 5 seconds.
[image]
Trigger the logic app, the request lasted a few seconds and response the result with both of the bodys from the two http request.

**So I think the response will contain all of the body from the http requests even if one of the http request last more time than the other http request**. So I think your logic app is no problem.